# select string between | symbols with and without the symbol itself

Tags: javascript, regex

How to get the string between `|` symbols with and without the symbols in regex?

Here is the string:

```
const string = "the sting here is an |string which goes between|.";
```

I want to select these two:

the first one:

```
|string which goes between|
```

and the second one:

```
string which goes between
```

I used `\|.*?\|` for getting the first one and `(?<=\|)(.*?)(?=\|)` for the second one with no luck.

Comment: @ dear Wiktor please reopen the question the links you provided does answer the issue ...

Comment: Oh, why lookarounds? All you need is `\|([^|]*)\|`. You get whole match and Group 1 with all necessary values: https://ideone.com/9m9OEi